# How to make discord bot to change script when command is used?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord, discord.js

The problem is, i have setup a discord bot with commands and responses. I wanna make it so for example when i use "!changeport 2222" in my discord channel, then it will change the actual code inside which should be changed to var port = 2222;. If i use "!changeport 80", then it should be changed to var port = 80; inside script.

I have tried several ways, but no luck. Im also not a professional coder.

```
var port = 80;
var portscanner = require('portscanner')
var used = false;

//command that is used in discord channel to change the port
client.on("message", (message) => {
var port = message.content.split(" ")[1]
var cooldowntext = ("You need to wait before using that command!")  
  if (message.content.startsWith("!port")) { 
     if(used) message.channel.send(cooldowntext);
     else{
    portscanner.checkPortStatus(port, '127.0.0.1', function(error, status) {
      // Status is 'open' if currently in use or 'closed' if available
      message.channel.send("Port changed to ");
      console.log(status)
      update()
      used = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
          used = false;
      }, 1000 * 10);

    })
     }


  }

});
//command that is used in discord channel to change the port /end/
```

Its not working the way i tried to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value of your first var:

```js
var port = 80;
var portscanner = require('portscanner')
var used = false;

//command that is used in discord channel to change the port
client.on("message", (message) => {
var newPort = message.content.split(" ")[1]
var cooldowntext = ("You need to wait before using that command!")  
  if (message.content.startsWith("!port")) { 
     if(used) message.channel.send(cooldowntext);
     else{
    port = newPort;
    portscanner.checkPortStatus(port, '127.0.0.1', function(error, status) {
      // Status is 'open' if currently in use or 'closed' if available
      message.channel.send("Port changed to ");
      console.log(status)
      update()
      used = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
          used = false;
      }, 1000 * 10);

    })
     }


  }

});
//command that is used in discord channel to change the port /end/
```

I replaced your second `port` var with `newPort` and change the first `port` value to the `newPort` value when the command is run.